# Mysql: calculate length time between two times in AM and PM

Tags: mysql, time

I need to calculate the difference between two columns which are of type `time`. The fields are named `start_time` and `end_time`. I use the function `timediff(s,e)` and it works well but some times it doesn't. For example when `end_time` is `00:00` which is considered as `12 AM` and `start_time` is `19:00` which is `7 PM` the difference function shows 19 hours (actually I also select `hour(timediff(s,e))`) while I expect it to be 5 hours.

How can I fix this?

---

I tried this

```
case 
    when finish_time < start_time then TIMEDIFF(timestamp('2021:01:02',finish_time),timestamp('2021:01:01',start_time))
    else TIMEDIFF(timestamp('2021:01:01',finish_time),timestamp('2021:01:01',start_time))
end as diff,
```

and it works

Answer (score 1):

As `00:00:00` is considered the start of a new day or even if you have an end time that is the day after the start time you will have to make your start and end field into DATETIME types. Also if you want the difference between the 2 times you should be using `timediff(end,start)`

Comment: I updated the question. Is this a good solution?

Comment: Dates are `'2021-01-02'` `yyyy-mm-dd`

Comment: If you tested it and it works then its fine

Comment: Thanks. Ye it is Ok. I was just looking for a best practice